# What bonuses do you receive for being elevated?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

Reading through the Sniper skill tree, I saw the following:

> **Damn Good Ground**: Confers +10 Aim and +10 Defense against enemies at
>   lower elevation, in addition to the usual elevation bonuses.

What are the default bonuses you receive for being elevated? Is it just Aim normally, or does it give a Defense bonus too? Does it just matter if you *are* elevated relative to your target, or does the *amount* of elevation matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By "Default", you get +20 Aim if you are at least one elevation above your opponent, though how the game determines what elevation you are at seems somewhat random.

Damn Good Ground stacks with this, effectively increasing the accuracy bonus by 50%.

Comment: The reason that elevation can appear random is because you need at least a full "unit" of height advantage, and so if you are above someone only a half-unit, you don't get the effect.

Answer (score -4):

on the pc each elevation is a f button only full elevation levels count it also raises crit

Comment: What does "f button only" mean?